# Java Zip File System Provider: ReadOnly on remote drive [Windows]

Tags: java, filesystems, zip, java.nio.file

I have a problem with [Zip File System Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html): If the zip file is on a remote drive (mapped or not seems to be irrelevant), the virtual file system is readonly, although the file itself is not. I wrote a minimal sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File workingDir = new File(args[0]);
    File source = new File(workingDir, "in.zip");
    File target = new File(workingDir, "out.zip");
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), target.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(target.toPath(), null)) {
        Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("test.xml");
        System.out.println("zipfile writable: " + target.canWrite());
        System.out.println("zipFS writable: " + !zipfs.isReadOnly());
        Files.delete(pathInZipfile);
        System.out.println("File successfully deleted");   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If workingDir is a local directory, everything works fine. However, if it is a (mapped) remote drive, i get:

```
zipfile writable: true
zipFS writable: false
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.ReadOnlyFileSystemException
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.checkWritable(ZipFileSystem.java:155)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.deleteFile(ZipFileSystem.java:1335)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.delete(ZipPath.java:655)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.delete(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:206)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
    at zipfs.ZipFS.main(ZipFS.java:23)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it impossible? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same thing and I looked at the JDK code.

#### Findings

In ZipFileSystem.java there are three relevant lines:

```
zfpath.getFileSystem().provider().checkAccess(zfpath, AccessMode.READ);
if (!Files.isWritable(zfpath))
    this.readOnly = true;
```

zfPath is a Path object.  Something in the Windows FileSystem provider blocks write access to a zip archive path.  Doesn't seem like there is much to be done about that.

#### Workaround

What I used as a workaround was to:

1. Create the zip archive in a temp folder
2. Populate the zip archive
3. Copy the temp file to the original mapped drive location

As long as the mapped drive is writable in contexts outside of the zip FileSystem, this method works.

Comment: Your workaround is what I ended up doing as well, there doesn't seem to be a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

We run in exactly the same problem, and have deviced somewhat barbarian solution.
`FileSystems.newFileSystem(Path)` accepts `Path` interface, so it's possible to satisfy it wrapping real `Path` instance.

Here is the solution that implements required `FileSysteProvider.checkAccess()`:

```java
  private static FileSystem createZip(Path zipPath)
    throws Exception
  {
    var fileSystem = zipPath.getFileSystem();
    var provider = fileSystem.provider();
    
    return FileSystems.newFileSystem(
      new Path()
      {
        private Path path(Path path)
        {
          return this == path ? zipPath : path;
        }
        
        @Override
        public FileSystem getFileSystem()
        {
          return new FileSystem()
          {
            public Set<String> supportedFileAttributeViews()
            {
              return fileSystem.supportedFileAttributeViews();
            }
            
            @Override
            public FileSystemProvider provider()
            {
              return new FileSystemProvider()
              {
                @Override
                public void setAttribute(
                  Path path, 
                  String attribute, 
                  Object value,
                  LinkOption... options) 
                  throws IOException
                {
                  provider.setAttribute(path(path), attribute, value, options);
                }
                
                @Override
                public Map<String, Object> readAttributes(
                  Path path, 
                  String attributes,
                  LinkOption... options) 
                  throws IOException
                {
                  return provider.
                    readAttributes(path(path), attributes, options);
                }
                
                @Override
                public <A extends BasicFileAttributes> A readAttributes(
                  Path path,
                  Class<A> type, 
                  LinkOption... options) 
                  throws IOException
                {
                  return provider.readAttributes(path(path), type, options);
                }
                
                @Override
                public FileSystem newFileSystem(URI uri, Map<String, ?> env)
                  throws IOException
                {
                  return provider.newFileSystem(uri, env);
                }
                
                @Override
                public DirectoryStream<Path> newDirectoryStream(
                  Path dir,
                  Filter<? super Path> filter) 
                  throws IOException
                {
                  return provider.newDirectoryStream(dir, filter);
                }
                
                @Override
                public SeekableByteChannel newByteChannel(
                  Path path,
                  Set<? extends OpenOption> options, 
                  FileAttribute<?>... attrs)
                  throws IOException
                {
                  return provider.newByteChannel(path(path), options, attrs);
                }
                
                @Override
                public void move(
                  Path source, 
                  Path target, 
                  CopyOption... options)
                  throws IOException
                {
                  provider.move(path(source), path(target), options);
                }
                
                @Override
                public boolean isSameFile(Path path, Path path2) 
                  throws IOException
                {
                  return provider.isSameFile(path(path), path(path2));
                }
                
                @Override
                public boolean isHidden(Path path) 
                  throws IOException
                {
                  return provider.isHidden(path(path));
                }
                
                @Override
                public String getScheme()
                {
                  return provider.getScheme();
                }
                
                @Override
                public Path getPath(URI uri)
                {
                  return provider.getPath(uri);
                }
                
                @Override
                public FileSystem getFileSystem(URI uri)
                {
                  return provider.getFileSystem(uri);
                }
                
                @Override
                public FileStore getFileStore(Path path) 
                  throws IOException
                {
                  return provider.getFileStore(path(path));
                }
                
                @Override
                public <V extends FileAttributeView> V getFileAttributeView(
                  Path path,
                  Class<V> type, 
                  LinkOption... options)
                {
                  return provider.
                    getFileAttributeView(path(path), type, options);
                }
                
                @Override
                public void delete(Path path) 
                  throws IOException
                {
                  provider.delete(path(path));
                }
                
                @Override
                public void createDirectory(Path dir, FileAttribute<?>... attrs)
                    throws IOException
                {
                  provider.createDirectory(path(dir), attrs);
                }
                
                @Override
                public void copy(
                  Path source, 
                  Path target, 
                  CopyOption... options)
                  throws IOException
                {
                  provider.copy(path(source), path(target), options);                      
                }
                
                @Override
                public void checkAccess(Path path, AccessMode... modes)
                  throws IOException
                {
                  if ((modes != null) && 
                    (modes.length == 1) && 
                    (modes[0] == AccessMode.WRITE))
                  {
                    return;
                  }
                  
                  provider.checkAccess(path(path), modes);
                }
              };
            }
            
            @Override
            public WatchService newWatchService()
              throws IOException
            {
              return fileSystem.newWatchService();
            }
            
            @Override
            public boolean isReadOnly()
            {
              return false;
            }
            
            @Override
            public boolean isOpen()
            {
              return fileSystem.isOpen();
            }
            
            @Override
            public UserPrincipalLookupService getUserPrincipalLookupService()
            {
              return fileSystem.getUserPrincipalLookupService();
            }
            
            @Override
            public String getSeparator()
            {
              return fileSystem.getSeparator();
            }
            
            @Override
            public Iterable<Path> getRootDirectories()
            {
              return fileSystem.getRootDirectories();
            }
            
            @Override
            public PathMatcher getPathMatcher(String syntaxAndPattern)
            {
              return fileSystem.getPathMatcher(syntaxAndPattern);
            }
            
            @Override
            public Path getPath(String first, String... more)
            {
              return fileSystem.getPath(first, more);
            }
            
            @Override
            public Iterable<FileStore> getFileStores()
            {
              return fileSystem.getFileStores();
            }
            
            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException
            {
              fileSystem.close();                  
            }
          };
        }
  
        @Override
        public boolean isAbsolute()
        {
          return zipPath.isAbsolute();
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path getRoot()
        {
          return zipPath.getRoot();
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path getFileName()
        {
          return zipPath.getFileName();
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path getParent()
        {
          return zipPath.getParent();
        }
  
        @Override
        public int getNameCount()
        {
          return zipPath.getNameCount();
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path getName(int index)
        {
          return zipPath.getName(index);
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path subpath(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
        {
          return zipPath.subpath(beginIndex, endIndex);
        }
  
        @Override
        public boolean startsWith(Path other)
        {
          return zipPath.startsWith(other);
        }
  
        @Override
        public boolean endsWith(Path other)
        {
          return zipPath.endsWith(other);
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path normalize()
        {
          return zipPath.normalize();
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path resolve(Path other)
        {
          return zipPath.relativize(other);
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path relativize(Path other)
        {
          return zipPath.relativize(other);
        }
  
        @Override
        public URI toUri()
        {
          return zipPath.toUri();
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path toAbsolutePath()
        {
          return zipPath.toAbsolutePath();
        }
  
        @Override
        public Path toRealPath(LinkOption... options) 
          throws IOException
        {
          return zipPath.toRealPath(options);
        }
  
        @Override
        public WatchKey register(
          WatchService watcher, 
          Kind<?>[] events,
          Modifier... modifiers) 
          throws IOException
        {
          return zipPath.register(watcher, events, modifiers);
        }
  
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Path other)
        {
          return zipPath.compareTo(other);
        }
      }, 
      Map.of("create", "true"));
  }
```

This is more like a hack but we think it solves the bug in original `ZipFileSystem`

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the private field `readOnly` in `ZipFileSystem` to `false` with reflection.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @LawrenceAiello: Technical incorrectness is not a good reason to delete an answer as being a misplaced comment. This is an answer, whether or not it works.