# Read specific property from a property file in a jar

Tags: java, zip, properties-file

I need to read the property "product.build.number" from the property file "version.properties" which lies at the root level of each of the jars. My naive approach is:

```
  private static int getProductBuildNumber(File artefactFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
  {
    try (ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(
        artefactFile)))
    {

      Set<String> possClasses = new HashSet<>();

      for (ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zip
          .getNextEntry())
      {
        if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().toLowerCase().equals(
            "version.properties"))
        {
          List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(zip, (String) null);

          for (String line : lines)
          {
            if (line.startsWith("product.build.number"))
            {
              String[] split = line.split("=");
              if (split.length == 2)
              {
                return Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
              }

            }
          }

        }
      }
    }

    throw new IOException("product.build.number not found.");

  }
```

I guess there are more elegant and reliable ways. Any ideas?

Comment: Your approach looks correct if you are reading property file from jar outside of classpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like (untested):

```
private static int getProductBuildNumber(Path artefactFilePath) throws IOException{
   try(FileSystem zipFileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(artefactFilePath, null)){
      Path versionPropertiesPath = zipFileSystem.getPath("/version.properties");
      Properties versionProperties = new Properties();
      try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(versionPropertiesPath)){
          versionProperties.load(is);
      }
      return Integer.parseInt(versionProperties.getProperty("product.build.number"));
   }
}
```

Comment: I have to notice that it will not in-memory unpacking. It requires writeable directory.

Comment: @vsminkov I'm not sure what you mean. The zip file system provider shipped with the JRE allows to access zip files using the NIO.2 File API. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: I mean this solution requires additional disk space to perform unpacking (here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863465/java-zip-file-system-provider-readonly-on-remote-drive-windows)). while `ZipInputStream` does unpacking in-memory.

Comment: @vsminkov No, it doesn't require additional disk space. It's all in-memory AFAIK. Where do you have this information from?

Comment: my bad :( I take it back. I wrongly recalled that [`ZipFileSystem#createTempFileInSameDirectoryAs(byte[])`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/demo/nio/zipfs/src/com/sun/nio/zipfs/ZipFileSystem.java#l1089) method is called upon unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t said whether the .jar files are are in your classpath.

If they are in your classpath, you should be using [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) to read the entry:

```
try (InputStream propStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/version.properties")) {
    // ...
}
```

If they .jar files are not in your classpath, you should create a jar: URL from the file.  The format of such a URL is described in the [JarURLConnection documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html).

Note that java.io.File is obsolete, and you should always use [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) instead:

```
private static int getProductBuildNumber(Path artefactFile)
throws IOException {
    URL propsURL = new URL("jar:" + artefactFile.toUri() + "!/version.properties");
    try (InputStream propStream = propsURL.openStream()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Regardless of the data’s location, you should always use the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class to read properties.  (Parsing a properties file yourself means you have to account for comments, Unicode escapes, continuation lines, and all possible name/value separators.)

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try (InputStream propStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/version.properties")) {
    props.load(propStream);
}

int buildNumber = Integer.parseInt(
    props.getProperty("product.build.number"));
```

Comment: getClass().getResourceAsStream won't work here, I think (multiple jars with a version.properties file at the same location - the default classloader only sees the first one)